# App crashing in cocos2d app on device when nothing happening

Tags: iphone, debugging, cocos2d-iphone

I have a somewhat simple game that I'm making and now that I'm testing what I consider a bare bone version of the app on devices, I keep getting crashes over and over. I'm fairly new at debugging on actual devices, so any help would be great.

The really weird part is that it will usually crash when nothing is firing. No touches, no animations, nothing is happening. I've tried running Instruments to check for memory leaks. All I find are two objects that are both created in the menu scene.

I'm changing scenes using

```
Game *game = [Game nodeWithPlayers:arr Tutorial:NO];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:game];
```

which sends some data (mainly # of players) to the Game scene. I put a comment in the dealloc of my menu scene and it fires, so I know that's happening.

The two objects that are reported as memory leaks are my MenuManager object that helps w/ some menu animations and positions in the menu scene, and my SoundManager object which at the moment only plays a couple bit wav file on buttons and a 9mb mp3 as background music. I just don't understand why those objects are even persisting if the menu scene is deallocated...

I'm not sure where to start w/ debugging these seemingly random crashes. Any advice?

Comment: What is the console output when it crashes.

Comment: Only error I get is a typical EXC_BAD_ACCESS with nothing in the console at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't crash on Simulator and the crash is "silent", it seems to be memory overhead. And if you load all resources at once there will be no memory warnings in console.

Try to run the app with Activity Monitor in Instruments - it measures real memory usage. And try to skip loading textures (inside `CCTexture2D` class comment `glTexImage2D(...)`.

Comment: Ok I've likely determined that this is the problem, so how do I go about solving it? I can play the game just fine, no crashing, by commenting out the `glTextImage2d(...)`.

Comment: As you say that crash occurs with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, it's not standard memory overhead problem. Can you show all console output on crash?